# using microsoft enterprise library in .net dll to be called from COM application

Tags: .net, com, dll, assemblies, enterprise-library

I created a c++ .net dll, in which I need to implement logging. I decided to go with Microsoft Enterprise Library's Logging.

Now, I am calling this dll from a COM application (I created a .tlb from the dll to use in the COM application), and the error I am getting is this:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I get around this??

TIA

Comment: Did you actually include the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common assembly in your .NET project?

Comment: yes, and the dll for that is there, in the debug folder of the dll.

Do I need to create a tlb for this dll as well? If yes, how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it working. I needed to create a tlb file for each of the dll's using regasm/tlb

Thanks